# How to access swift code in main target from objective-c code from test target?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift2, interop, xcode7.3

I have swift class descendant of `NSObject` and marked with `@objc`. I done everything described in [Apple doc about interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122) and numerous question on stack overflow. My *`Xcode-generated header`* (`TargetName-Swift.h`) is *created* by Xcode (I know it for sure - it is in derived data folder, and I can access swift code within the same target from objc by importing `TargetName-Swift.h`). However, I can't access *`Xcode-generated header`* from my unit tests target. Xcode complains that `#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h> file not found`. I've checked product/module name multiple times - they are correct.

It won't be found even in new project created with Xcode 7.3. (despite settings `Defines module` to `YES`, declaring swift classes public, @objc and descendant of NSObject/ViewController/etc)

What am I doing wrong? Could it be a bug in Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the only way to access swift code from objective-c code in different target is to add `Xcode-generated header` to `User Header Search Path` in target where objective-c code located.

In case your swift code is in main target and objective-c in tests target you could use `$(CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME).build/DerivedSources`. Note that this path assumes that your main target has the same name as `Project name` (in most cases its true since Xcode creates such names by default).